# Why does apt-get install throw "Extracting templates from packages" to stderr?

Tags: debian, stderr, apt

When I run apt-get install, even in quiet mode `-qq` and by redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`, I still have the following message displayed in stderr :

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
```

Why is this message in stderr ?

Answer (score 1):

it's not `apt` that emits this message but [`dpkg-preconfigure`](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/-/blob/9ed58c21/dpkg-preconfigure#L180), a tool that is used by `apt`, but otherwise follows its own rules: obviously these rules do not include honoring flags passed to `apt`.

Comment: I know, I'm too late to the party, but anyway... Is it possible to push all such messages (the ones coming from tools triggered by `apt`, or any other package for that matter) to a custom function?